# How to bring the selected div on top of all other div's

Tags: javascript, z-index

I have a bunch of divs on the screen.
What I want to do is, when I select any div, I want its zIndex to be always higher than all other divs.

In my application, i will need to do this repeatedly whenever I select a div, put it on top of others.

Is this possible using Javascript?

Answer (score 12):

In some cases, you can bring an element to top without using CSS directly. If you place your DIVs to the body tag or under another parent element, you can re-append itself to the parent. JavaScript will move it to the last position in the child list which will bring the element in a "natural" way to the top.

Example:

```
myElement.parentNode.appendChild(myElement);
```

I used this trick for my custom context menu. Works without zIndex.

Comment: This is what probably most of the people is looking for.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, very much so.

HTML:

```
<div>foo</div>
<div>bar</div>
<div>bas</div>
```

Javascript:

```
//Collect all divs in array, then work on them
var all = document.selectElementsByTagName("div");
var prev = false;
      
for(i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    all[i].onclick = function() {
        all[i].style.position = 'relative'; //necessary to use z-index
        if (prev) { prev.style.zIndex = 1; }
            this.style.zIndex = 1000;
            prev = this;
        }
    }
}
```

//Edit: Sorry, forgot a brace. Corrected now.

Comment: Never knew `z-index` depended on `position: relative` I just thought it had issues... that is the important part here.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend setting a variable at the beginning and incrementing that.

```
var top_z = 10;

function bringToTop(element)
{
    element.style.zIndex = ++top_z;
}
```

(++top_z increments and then returns top_z)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that:

```
var my_index = 100; //global var on page
function sendontop(div_id) {
  if (typeOf(div_id)=="string") {
    div_id=document.getElementById(div_id);
  }
  div_id.style.zIndex = my_index++;
}
```

on the object

```
<div id="bringmeup" onclick="sendontop(this);" >somecontent</div>
```

or otherwise you can also use

```
sendontop("bringmeup");
```

i came across this problem and solved like that

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps!

```
document.getElementById("mainactiondiv").firstElementChild.appendChild(bubble);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (a modified version of Ben's solution, because it generated so many errors).
When you click the element, it should go to the top.
Hope it helps!

```js
var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div"); //Changed variable name to 'allDivs' because the name 'all' generated an error.
var prev = false;

for(ii = 0; ii < allDivs.length; ii++) { // changed the for variable to 'ii' instead of 'i'  so i can find it easier (searching for 'i' will return avery instance of the letter i, even inside words, not just the variable, whereas ii is unique).
    allDivs[ii].onclick = function() {
  this.style.position = 'absolute'; //You have to have a position type defined. It doesn't matter what type, you just have to. If you define it elsewhere in your styles you can remove this.
        if (prev) { prev.style.zIndex = 1; }
        this.style.zIndex = 1000;
        prev = this;
    }
}
```

```css
div {
  padding:20px;
  border:2px solid black;
  border-radius:4px;
}
#d4 {
  background-color:lightblue;
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:20px;
}
#d3 {
  background-color:lightgreen;
  position:absolute;
  top:70px;
  left:20px;
}
#d2 {
  background-color:yellow;
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:70px;
}
#d1 {
  background-color:pink;
  position:absolute;
  top:70px;
  left:70px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div id="d1">div1</div>
  <div id="d2">div2</div>
  <div id="d3">div3</div>
  <div id="d4">div4</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. It traverses all elements on the page and increases the max z-index by 1.

Note that this method still works when there have been dynamically increased z indices on the page as well:

```
function bring_to_front(target_id) {    
    const all_z = [];
    document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(function(elem) {
        all_z.push(elem.style.zIndex)
    })
    const max_index = Math.max.apply(null, all_z.map((x) => Number(x)));
    const new_max_index = max_index + 1;
    document.getElementById(target_id).style.zIndex = new_max_index;
}
```

Simply pass-in the `id` of the element you wish to bring to the front.